# Inscribing text into an object

Tags: text-object

I have a cube, and I would like it to have a text inscribed in it, so the text would be in the cube but we could see it. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Bcc.png)?

Comment: Yes, like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also use *Knife Project*.

- Subdivide the face you want to be engraved (knife project needs some geometry)
- Place the text above the face.
- Select the text
- Select the cube (must be the active object)
- Change to *Edit Mode*
- Click Knife Project
- Extrude the selected faces (in or out)

[image]

Comment: `Place the above the face.`?

Comment: Just adding note to future answer seekers. Cut will be made based on which angle you are looking at. So keep your viewport at the angle where you want cut. For example, if you want cut from top, use ortho top view while if you want cut as specific angle, put viewport at that angle.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways to do this:

1.) You could apply a texture of a text, and use it as a displacement in the displacement modifier.

2.) You could create your text with blender text (add some thickness to it), then tessellate it so it becomes a mesh, and then apply a boolean operator on your cube with the text (depending on, if want it inscribed or extruded appearance).

I would recommend (2.) as it involves much cleaner operations.

Here is a quick workflow, for different results use a different boolean operator.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]