# Engrave Text onto an irregular surface

Tags: modeling, text-object

I've searched thoroughly and while there are plenty of questions and answers on how to engrave text into an object none seem to work for me as i am using an irregular surface.
I have the following Model
[image: Model]

And when attempting to use a boolean modifier (The text has been converted to a mesh) with difference The following is the result:

[image: Model After Modifier]

Side View:
[image: Model from Side]

as you can see that hasn't come out at all as I wanted it
(I hoped it would only cut away what was inside the main model and fill the bottom as other answers have shown:
[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/engraving-a-text-string-in-blender-internal-render) and [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14698/inscribing-text-into-an-object))

Some Letters do cut correctly like the very first but the colours are still messed up.

So My question is, Is there a way to cut/engrave text into an irregularly shaped surface that sits flush with that surface.

Edit: File as requested:
[image]

Comment: also a side image of the model http://i.imgur.com/Obo1Df2.png, unfortunately i could not post in the main post as i dont have sufficient reputation

Comment: Added the pic to the post. Feel free to move it.

Comment: It may be worth trying to show the engraved details using the normal map. As to what I tried, it appears I should've increased the polycount of the main curved object up to 150k, which isn't good. And the shading still wasn't satisfying enough (only if the camera isn't that closely).

Comment: What is the topology of the main object (irregularly shaped one) ? It should be quite dense in order either Boolean or Knife Project to take (desirable) effect. You can increase the polygons' density only there so to save render times.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? sorry I'm very new to modeling with blender so I'm not very well versed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "staff" object has many duplicate vertices and all normals are inside, boolean can't work.

1. In Edit mode, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove doubles*,
2. After fixing duplicates, select all, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to fix normals
3. apply boolean modifier to object "staff" with type of *Operation* set to *Difference*, with object "Esvele"

In order to see the effect, hide object "Esvele" or set its "maximum draw type" to "bounds".

[image]

Adding pictures for the whole process...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I hope it is clearer now... you just have to set boolean for every other text, now, it will work and have the right color......

Comment: thank you very much. as I said I'm pretty new to this so id didn't think there would be issues with just duplicating the object and making it a mirror so they are one thanks for your help. only problem is when i press W I have no option to remove duplicates only to retrict render and clear restricted render

Comment: Is there perhaps a sub menu somewhere that I can rather use as I've noticed from alot of posts my hotkeys seem different

Comment: Edit: Turns out my version is hideously old (2014-04-10) so perhaps updating is in order

Comment: @kylehendry you should [enter Edit mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/introduction.html) to execute `Ctrl`+`N` and `W` operations in a described way.

Comment: attempted it again and when using remove doubles it says nothing was removed and after fixing the normals the same issue happens again

Comment: also is there anyway to fix that weird purple colour? i think its using the ends material instead of the staff but ive no idea how to fix it

Comment: double check doubles and normals, or the boolean will not work. Then that object has 2 materials "staff.003" and "jam" (jam is purple). After applying the boolean, you can assign those vertices to "staff.003" (just select them, select the material, and press "assign").  Before applying the boolean, those new faces (engraved letters) get the first material (jam). You can set "staff.003" as first, though.

Comment: see added pictures...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Only problem that remains is my computer is so bad it can't do the basic process of removing duplicates without freezing.